# Change password on WP7 SQL Server CE database

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) describes how to ecrypt and password protect a local SQL Server CE database on a WP7 device.

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext ("Data Source='isostore:/MyDatabase.sdf';Password='mypassword'");
if (!db.DatabaseExists()) db.CreateDatabase();
```

I've not been able to find how to change that password once set. Is this possible? For that matter, is it possible to remove the password and encryption once created?

Comment: No, neither is possible - I explore the subject further here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/03/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html

Comment: Post as an answer and I'll accept. It's unfortunate there isn't more direct compatibility between the desktop and WP7 databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, neither is possible, as there is no ADO.NET access, on access via LINQ to SQL - I explore the subject further on my blog here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/03/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html